# C# RDLC Report - Directly to Printer - Format Collapses

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, printing, ssrs-2012

I am using a ssrs client rdlc report (3-inch printer) in our WPF application.
when the report rendered to.PDF and save it to a temporary path, and then prints the PDF means it works perfectly. 
But when I try to directly print the report to the printer, the report renders as Image (code for printing suggested from MSDN site), but prints only the half of the report in the printer and that too ugly to see as it looks like a drag.

Report Width : 3.5in
Report Height: 7in 
please take a look at the code below I use and suggest your opinions.

```
    // RDLC InvoicePrintReport - Report Ready with Data Source and Parameters
      Export(InvoicePrintReport);
      Print();

    //Report Printing Section
    private int m_currentPageIndex;
    private IList<Stream> m_streams;

    private Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, System.Text.Encoding encoding,
        string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    private void Export(LocalReport report)
    {
        string deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat><PageWidth>3.5in</PageWidth><MarginTop>0.01in</MarginTop><MarginLeft>0.01in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0.1in</MarginRight><MarginBottom>0.01in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>";
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);
        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams) stream.Position = 0;
    }

    private void Print()
    {
        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0) throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            //PaperSize pkCustomSize1 = new PaperSize("First custom size", 100, 200);
            //printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pkCustomSize1;

            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }

    private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile pageImage =
            new System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

        // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
        System.Drawing.Rectangle adjustedRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
            ev.PageBounds.Left - (int) ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
            ev.PageBounds.Top - (int) ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY, ev.PageBounds.Width, ev.PageBounds.Height);

        // Draw a white background for the report
        ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

        // Draw the report content
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

        // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
        m_currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
    }
```

[reference:printing local report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost had the answer in my question itself. the issue is with the paper size property.
now changed the paper size as mentioned below for the 3-Inch Print does the trick.

```
    private void Print()
    {
        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0) throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            PaperSize pkCustomSize1 = new PaperSize("First custom size", 350, 700);
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pkCustomSize1;

            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }
```

Note:
350 - Width - Hundredth of Inches 
700 - Height - Hundredth of Inches (AutoCut will do the rest in thermal Printer , so not exactly 700 required)